# String indices must be integers error

Tags: python

I am looking to parse out json obtained from following code:

```
import json
from watson_developer_cloud import ToneAnalyzerV3Beta
import urllib.request
import codecs
reader = codecs.getreader("utf-8")
tone_analyzer = ToneAnalyzerV3Beta(
    url='https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/tone-analyzer/api',
    username='<username>',
    password='<password>',
    version='2016-02-11')

data=json.dumps(tone_analyzer.tone(text='I am very happy'), indent=2)
print (data)

for cat in data['document_tone']['tone_categories']:
    print('Category:', cat['category_name'])
    for tone in cat['tones']:
        print('-', tone['tone_name'])
```

and keep running into error:string indices must be integers
Not sure where I am dropping the ball but I would really appreciate any help with this one.

Comment: They will still be accessible so you may want to change your password too.

Comment: json.dumps() return a string. If you want to use the json as a python object (ie accessing with ['key']), you must either use json.loads(data), either use tone_analyser...)

Comment: I took the liberty of editing your post, to remove the credentials. They will still be visible in the edit history, however. So as @ayhan says, you should change your password ASAP!!!

Answer (score 1):

`json.dumps()` converts an object into a string. So, `data` is a string. So, you can't index it with `'document_tone'` key (it's not a `dict`). Maybe you meant `json.loads()`? Or maybe `tone_analyzer.tone()` already returns a `dict` and there is no need for `loads()`?

Comment: Based on updates (posted as answers) from the OP, `tone_analyzer.tone()` does return a `dict` so the second part is the right answer.