# string indices must be integers error with json

Tags: python, json

I am trying to parse out following json using pythong:

```
{  
   "document_tone":{  
      "tone_categories":[  
         {  
            "tones":[  
               {  
                  "score":0.044115,
                  "tone_id":"anger",
                  "tone_name":"Anger"
               },
               {  
                  "score":0.005631,
                  "tone_id":"disgust",
                  "tone_name":"Disgust"
               },
               {  
                  "score":0.013157,
                  "tone_id":"fear",
                  "tone_name":"Fear"
               },
               {  
                  "score":1.0,
                  "tone_id":"joy",
                  "tone_name":"Joy"
               },
               {  
                  "score":0.058781,
                  "tone_id":"sadness",
                  "tone_name":"Sadness"
               }
            ],
            "category_id":"emotion_tone",
            "category_name":"Emotion Tone"
         },
         {  
            "tones":[  
               {  
                  "score":0.0,
                  "tone_id":"analytical",
                  "tone_name":"Analytical"
               },
               {  
                  "score":0.0,
                  "tone_id":"confident",
                  "tone_name":"Confident"
               },
               {  
                  "score":0.0,
                  "tone_id":"tentative",
                  "tone_name":"Tentative"
               }
            ],
            "category_id":"language_tone",
            "category_name":"Language Tone"
         },
         {  
            "tones":[  
               {  
                  "score":0.0,
                  "tone_id":"openness_big5",
                  "tone_name":"Openness"
               },
               {  
                  "score":0.571,
                  "tone_id":"conscientiousness_big5",
                  "tone_name":"Conscientiousness"
               },
               {  
                  "score":0.936,
                  "tone_id":"extraversion_big5",
                  "tone_name":"Extraversion"
               },
               {  
                  "score":0.978,
                  "tone_id":"agreeableness_big5",
                  "tone_name":"Agreeableness"
               },
               {  
                  "score":0.975,
                  "tone_id":"emotional_range_big5",
                  "tone_name":"Emotional Range"
               }
            ],
            "category_id":"social_tone",
            "category_name":"Social Tone"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

and here is the code that I am trying to use following code to get tone name and score from the json:

```
import json
from watson_developer_cloud import ToneAnalyzerV3Beta
import urllib.request
import codecs
reader = codecs.getreader("utf-8")
tone_analyzer = ToneAnalyzerV3Beta(
    url='https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/tone-analyzer/api',
    username='<username>',
    password='<password>',
    version='2016-02-11')

data=json.dumps(tone_analyzer.tone(text='I am very happy'), indent=2)
print (data)

for cat in data['document_tone']['tone_categories']:
    print('Category:', cat['category_name'])
    for tone in cat['tones']:
        print('-', tone['tone_name'])
```

but keep running into the error string indices must be integers. I tried to ask the same question in one of my earlier post but with this post I am providing some more details.
I would really appreciate any inputs with this.

Thank You

Comment: Than why didn't you update your previous question instead of creating new one? There is `edit` link after tags in post.

Comment: *"I tried to ask the same question in one of my earlier post (...) "* Just in case you didn't know, you can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/37528517/edit) your questions to add more details if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

```
tone_analyzer.tone(text='I am very happy')
```

returns a dictionary, there is no need to use `json` to modify the data in any way, just do

```
X = tone_analyzer.tone(text='I am very happy')
```

Note that you have already [recieved this exact answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37528595/5827215) on your previous question.